# Google plus sign in not responding

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to integrate google+ sign in into android application I followed all steps from official documentation,Generated OAuth 2 client id,Configuration file in app dir, Adding dependencies in build gradle,Permissions.But when i click on google sign in button it shows popup for email account select and after account select,It asks for permissions to allow,and it stops without any error,handleSignInResults always coming false.Even i tried creating different application with same package,Still the same.
Android version 6.0,Google services 9.4,gradle 2.0,Can anyone suggest me any tutorial which helps me to create sign in easily.ThankYou
Here is my Java Code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();on
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}


  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
   private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();
        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to handle `onRequestPermissionsResult()` also

Comment: put your .java file here

Comment: please check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: I edited the question with javacode,Can anyone tell what is problem?

Comment: I tried androidHive tutorial but it is still giving same ,HandlesignIn result is still false.Not able to figure out the reason.